# Asynchronous remote service does not define corresponding method

Tags: java, gwt, intellij-idea, gxt

My GWT app is written in the IDEA. to make gwt RPC calls I create two interfaces.
the first one:

```
RemoteServiceRelativePath("ServerManagement")
public interface ServerManagement extends RemoteService {

String userLogin(String customerId, String login, String password) throws Exception;

ArrayList<PropertyItem> getProperties(String customerId) throws Exception;

void receive(String customerId) throws Exception;
```

and the second async one:

```
public interface ServerManagementAsync {

    void userLogin(String customerId, String login, String password, AsyncCallback<String> asyncCallback);
    void getProperties(String customerId, AsyncCallback<ArrayList<PropertyItem>> asyncCallback);
    void receive(String customerId, AsyncCallback<String> asyncCallback);       
}
```

but in both interfaces the line with the "receive" method undrelined red and the ide returns the message:

```
Methods of asynchronous remote service 'ServerManagementAsync' are not consistent with 'ServerManagement' less... (Ctrl+F1) 
This inspection reports any inconsistency between a methods of synchronous and asynchronous interfaces of remote service
```

How to fix this?

Comment: I tried this in Eclipse and it doesn't complain. Are your imports right? I'm thinking here specifically of `PropertyItem`.

Comment: PropertyItem is not mentioned in "receive" method, so I don't understand you. imports right. IDE talks only that there is an inconsistency. nevertheless, maven compiles this and the application works well.

Comment: Oh sorry I didn't notice it was for `receive()`. I'll I can think of is what @AVolpe said in his answer.

Answer (score 2):

The Async interface must be:

```
public interface ServerManagementAsync {

    void userLogin(String customerId, String login, String password, AsyncCallback<String> asyncCallback);
    void getProperties(String customerId, AsyncCallback<ArrayList<PropertyItem>> asyncCallback);
    void receive(String customerId, AsyncCallback<Void> asyncCallback);       
}
```

Note the AsyncCallback <Void> in the method receive, the AsyncCallback must be parametrized with the Type returned by the method in the sync interface.

Sorry for my bad english.
Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the answer above.  I also want to mention that I was seeing the exact same error, "Methods of asynchronous remote service are not consistent" when IntelliJ IDEA 12 was attempting to auto-generate the Asynchronous interface in the target/generated-sources folder on build.  I believe this to be a bug in IDEA.  Adding the function manually to the generated Async interface within the generated-sources directory fixed the error for me and actually caused IDEA to generate the file correctly on future compilations, even if I delete the generated-sources folder and recompile.

in Nikitin's case, it appears to be the result of his manually-coded Async interface "receive" method's AsyncCallback parameter having being typed as

```
AsyncCallback<String>  // does not work - String is not the synchronous method's return type
```

when it should be

```
AsyncCallback<Void>   // works, type matches with the synchronous method's return type
```

The recieve method's AsyncCallback type needs to be Void because that matches with the void return type of the receive method in the synchronous interface defined in ServerManagement.java.

Here's a screenshot:

[image: these types must match]